# Converting Integer into date objective --year and month--?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, type-conversion

I have a dataframe consisting two features of date and Id, as follows:

```
    dataframe:

     Id,       date     
     01,      1444953600
     02,      1473206400
```

I have used the following code to convert it from date to integer:

```
      dataframe['date']=dataframe['date'].astype("int64") // 10**9
```

Then, I tried the below code to re-convert the date into date object:

```
        dataframe.date = pd.to_datetime(dataframe.date,         
         dayfirst=True)
```

By running the above code, I recieve a very strange result, which is not correct as follows:

```
 dataframe:
          Id,          date
          01   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000144495
          02   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000147320
```

Date 1970 is not the correct date. My desired output should be like this: e.g,

```
     dataframe:
             Id,          date
             01        2016-01
             02        2016-05
```

Any idea to handle this  in an efficient way?

Comment: Sorry can you explain how you arrive at that date? What does date represent here? It isn't epoch time as `pd.to_datetime(1444953600, unit='s')` returns `Timestamp('2015-10-16 00:00:00')`

Comment: I have updated the question, and added the code that I used to reach to above integer.

Comment: Can you post what your original data looked like, by dividing and casting to and int you've lost whatever your original value is, it's really unhelpful what you've posted so far

Comment: Your first code "pd.to_datetime(1444953600, unit='s')" can handle the problem and I receive what you posted. Tnx. It woks